# How to format output one word per line

Tags: command-line, text-formatting

I logged into the linux system and try to get all the current users. I used `users` command in terminal and the result is displayed as "user1 user2 user3 user4".

Are there any ways to break the username line and make each username occupy one line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
users | tr -s ' ' '\n'
```

This will take the output of the `users` utility and replace all spaces with newlines using `tr`, removing multiple consecutive newlines from the result (with `-s`).

Pipe that through `sort -u` to get unique usernames.

Answer (score 3):

There are probably better ways but:

```
for user in $(users); do echo "$user"; done
```

or using the `fmt` command:

```
users | fmt -w 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplest solution, no pipe used:

```
printf '%s\n' $(users)
```

Comment: This does use a pipe, but one less fork than many solutions. It needs the pipe to get the data from the `users` process.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with this, leveraging 'who', awk, sort and uniq.

```
who | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort | uniq
```

This makes the assumption that you want unique user names and not each login session.

Answer (score -1):

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37843747/52074 this solution has 6 upvotes:

```
users | xargs -n 1
```